# How can I exclude certain categories from a product loop in Elementor / woocommerce

Tags: loops, woocommerce, product, categories, elementor

I am using Elementor Pro and WooCommerce. I have set up a shop page (not the woocommerce default store page) and included the "Products" element.

[image: see screen shot below]

But I want to exclude a certain category (i.e. "For Sale")

[image: see screen shot below]

However the front end still shows ALL products.

Can I use a snippet to exclude this category (or am I missing something in the Elementor or Woocommerce settings?

Answer (score 0):

You should enter the category name in the term field. It works for me like this
[image]